# Determine what salt state files will be pushed to node

Tags: match, state, salt-stack

Given a node id or matcher, is there a way to determine what state files will be pushed on a `state.highstate` - without actually running them? i.e. like a dry run.

I have a lot of templating going on in my state files and would like to see what would actually be affected before committing to a run.

Comment: Pretty sure this should be tagged as salt-stack, not salt. "salt" on its own refers to crypographic salts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what states are being applied by top to a given set of servers with `salt $MATCHER state.show_top`.

You can do a dry run with `salt $MATCHER state.highstate test=True` (case sensitive). I don't entirely trust it; sometimes it claims something should get changed, but when I run a real highstate, it turns up clean. I have never had the opposite occur, thankfully.